# Very slow app debug startup, maybe "lldb-rpc-server" related?

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, debugging, startup

I have a strange behavior for a few days. **Every** debug start in **any** iOS project on a physical device (MacOS projects start up normally) that I'm working on (even in a **blank ne**w project) lasts between one minute (on a USB connection) and over two minutes (on) a Wi-Fi connection). That's so annoying! I use Xcode 11.2.1 and Xcode 11.3 Beta, the same result on both. The host system is macOS 10.15.1 on a Macbook Pro Retina 15 inch (late 2012). The app will always hang in the home screen until it finally launches. While booting over a WiFi connection, a process called "llbd-rpc-server" receives several megs from the iOS device over the WiFi network, even on a completely **empty sample projec**t! I have never had this problem before! I have a backup system that does not experience this issue (same Xcode and MacOS version). So, is this an Xcode setting in the context of LLDB? I have already disabled all breakpoints, no change! Please help!

Comment: I'm suddenly having the same issue.
Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I have iMac and macbook, and two iPhones 11pro and SE. The only combination that hangs is iMac and iPhone 11pro. If I try to debug on macbook, it works, if I try to debug on iMac with iPhone SE it works.
If I turn off "Debug executable" under Edit scheme it also works...
I tried restarting iPhone and iMac, reinstalling the Xcode, deleting derived data etc. Nothing helps...
This is so frustrating :(

Comment: I fixed it indeed, but only by restoring a recent backup of the whole system. I did every update since then and the issue never reappeared since ... so hopefully it will never come back!

Comment: Same problem. Did you fix it?

Comment: I could fix it indeed, but only by restoring a recent backup of the whole system. I did every OS update since then and the issue never reappeared ... so hopefully it will never come back! I could not find out the cause though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been suffering with this for a couple of weeks.  I finally found https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123068 which includes the helpful hint:

> I deleted folders inside ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/
>   (folder's name started with 12.4.6), then run Xcode and launch an app
>   again, problem solved.

Which did in fact finally solve my issue.

Comment: I had the same issue with Xcode 12.0.1 and iPhone 11 Pro with iOS 14. Deleting all `iOS DeviceSupport/14*` subfolders solved it for me. Thanks!